# What happens when I input a wrong variable type using cin?

Tags: c++, cin, variable-types

I declared two integer variables and structured the program to get the values through `cin` and print out the values through `cout`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a , b;
  cin >> a >> b ;
  cout << endl << a << "\t" << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When prompted to input values I deliberately gave a non-integer value for the first variable and got the following **output**:

1. `char`: 0 and 32767
2. `float` 0 and 0
3. Absurdly large number: 2147483647 and 32767

**Why does the output of the *second variable* differ based on the *variable type* of the first input?**

Comment: Time to [read the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) - specifically the bit that starts with "If extraction fails".

Comment: Are you using C++11 or newer?

Comment: Look at the state of the stream in each case.

Comment: If there is a failure, then subsequent reading might not really read. Also, depending on the type more or less on the input would be read so the position might differ after first read.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks for the link. It really helped!